# posting stuff in drupal 7 without publishing it

Tags: drupal-7

So I have the following function in my drupal module. 
I want to submit the product as unpublished. I guess I will need to put

```
->condition('n.status', '1')
```

I just do not know where to put it.

Here is my method.

```
 function products_add(){
           global $user;
           $products = create('products');
           return drupal_get_form('products_form', $products);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
->condition('n.status', '1')
```

That code alone will not publish a node. To understand why you need to read http://drupal.org/node/310069

Also, the function product_add() is not where you should be doing this anyway. You need to use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) on the form products_form, and then default the published status to TRUE. Or, you could probably set this by doing **$node->status = NODE_PUBLISHED;** in [hook_node_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7). Or, you could also do something similar in [hook_entity_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/7).

Comment: Yep, I found that out too. 
i need to put the following code:

Comment: found out it is a pending issue in drupal http://drupal.org/node/1511662#comment-6158042

Comment: I'm not understanding how this is relevant to your question. The issue you are highlighting is related to the Services module. You did not mention in your initial question you are trying to save a node from an external location outside of Drupal. I would recommend being more descriptive in your question in future.